# Wrong network used on metamask by mistake

Tags: ether, metamask, addresses, network, rinkeby

I have bought some HUR tokens through metamask (transaction is confirmed) but cannot see the tokens in the wallet. I sent the ETH over main network, instead of rinkeby test network- what can i do??

Comment: You will have to ask the HUR team how to proceed. But it is kinda of strange that their crowdsale is running on rinkeby which is a testnet and ether is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Does the transaction that's been confirmed show the tokens being sent back or have any data/events of tokens?

Have you read their whitepaper to understand the token economics before, during, and after the sale?

Seems like the team has created this page to track your token transactions:

Hurify Token sale — “[My Token](https://medium.com/@Hurify/hurify-token-sale-my-token-page-is-enabled-now-80f25f6c7f70)” page is enabled now